# How to wait until service is bound?

Tags: java, android, java-8, android-service, android-service-binding

I'm programing a Bluetooth Service for my application. I don't know a lot about services in android but I managed to start one and use it the way I want.

My problem comes just on the very start when I try to use a function from the service on the `onCreate()` method from Activity (It doesnt have enought time to bind the service).

I structurated the code into 3 classes:

- BluetoothService:
  Class that implements the service

  ```
  public class BluetoothService extends Service implements IScanService {

      private final IBinder bluetoothBinder = new BluetoothBinder();

      @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
          return bluetoothBinder;
      }

      public class BluetoothBinder extends Binder {
          public BluetoothService getService() {
              return BluetoothService.this;
          }
      }

      // Other functions
  }
  ```
- BluetoothActivity:
  Abstract class (for reusability) that handles bluetooth service connection.

  ```
  public abstract class BluetoothActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      protected BluetoothService bluetoothService;
      protected volatile Boolean isBound = false;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          // Connecting to the service
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, BluetoothService.class);
          bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
      }

      private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

         @Override
          public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
             BluetoothService.BluetoothBinder binder = (BluetoothService.BluetoothBinder) service;
              bluetoothService = binder.getService();
              isBound = true;
          }

          @Override
          public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
              isBound = false;
          }
      };

      // Other functions
  }
  ```
- ScanActivity:
  Activity class that extends from BluetoothActivity and use BluetoothService methods on 'onCreate()'.

Variable 'isBound' is intended to be use in order to know if the service is bound (or if we have to wait).

What I tried:

- Use 'wait()' and 'notify()' but didn't worked for me.
- Use 'while(!isBound)' to wait but the application just crash.
- Use handlers to wait x miliseconds. This worked but I know is not the way since the service may not be bound.

So my question is how can I wait on the 'onCreate()' method until 'isBound' gets true?

Comment: You can't. It'll block the main thread, which will crash the app (ANR)

Comment: Yeah I noticed that when I tried, so I'm here asking.

Comment: Whats the point ? while you have `onServiceConnected()`.

Comment: I cannot use 'onServiceConnected()' because I want to separete the code to connect to the service because I will use it on diferent Activities that will extend the 'BluetoothActivity' so they would have acces to 'bluetoothService' methods.

Comment: @Zoe Where I can use 'wait()' ?? I can move the code into the 'onResume()' method if necessary.

Comment: you have ServiceConnection for that, this is the only way you can follow

Comment: After several hours I realised that I could make two new functions on `BluetoothService`, call them on `onServiceConnected()` and `onServiceDisconnected()`, and just override them at the extended class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized I can create two functions on `BluetoothService` and call them on `onServiceConnected()` and  `onServiceDisconnected()`:

```
private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
        BluetoothActivity.this.onServiceConnected(name, (BluetoothService.BluetoothBinder) binder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        BluetoothActivity.this.onServiceDisconnected(name);
    }
};

protected void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, BluetoothService.BluetoothBinder binder){
    bluetoothService = binder.getService();
}

protected void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name){
    bluetoothService = null;
}
```

And then just override them on the extended class:

```
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, BluetoothService.BluetoothBinder binder) {
    super.onServiceConnected(name, binder);
    //TODO
}

@Override
protected void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    // TODO
    super.onServiceDisconnected(name);
}
```